# How to change an image in a pictureBox when a List item is chosen in a dataGrid [C#] (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagrid, picturebox

I am working to create something akin to a "Pokedex" in Visual Studio 2012/13 (It basically is a Pokedex at the moment). It is a WinForm program, and so far I have a data grid that is listing off the "Pokemon's" list number, its name, and type. What I want to do next is have a pictureBox element show the image of the Pokemon (extracted from a list of image links) when that specific dataGrid list item is chosen (So if #4, Charmander, is chosen in the dataGrid, then I want it to show a picture of Charmander in the pictureBox).

This here is an example of the visual design of the project so far:

[image]

The empty space under the richTextBox is where the pictureBox is. Later on the Pokemon's description will also be included in that box when the list item is chosen, but I believe that will be easy to implement once I understand how to call the image at selection.

All and any help is appreciated! I am not including code for the project right now as I do not know what is helpful or not. Do let me know what is needed for a better understanding of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `ImageList` control to your form and add your Pokemon pictures to your ImageList. You can easily do that using the designer Images Collection property of the `ImageList`.

In addition, make sure to set your image indices as your Pokemons in your `DataGridView` (so the first image in the collection is Bulbassur, second is Ivysaur etc.) - this will later help you easy access a picture by its index.

Next step is to attach `CellEnter` event to your `DataGridView`. It will fire when a cell is focused.
Add this code to the event handler:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[e.RowIndex];
    } 
}
```

Note that this will only change the image if you select any of the first column (DexNum) cells. You could change it to whatever you like, change the condition.

I have not made any validation, you should do so, but I'm assuming that the number of rows is equal to the number of images.

Comment: So at the moment, this halts and tells me that an Index cannot be set to 0. Changing it to any other number simply does not do anything for the program. Any suggestions on where to go next? (Full error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.)

Comment: Ah, I dont know how it was fixed, but I messed around a bit more and it worked just fine after that...don't know what fixed it, but it ended up working OK. Thanks very much for the help and support!